# Tangents to a circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

[image]

For this construction, how would you show that the perimeter of the triangle $CDF$ is equal to $2BC$? Please include steps and whatnot.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE , what have you tried till now ?

Comment: I am absolutely lost in fact. A and C, and B and C are the same lengths?

Comment: Yes, $AC=BC$ is one step in a proof. Similar formulas apply starting with $F$ and with $D$ instead of $C$.

Comment: @Lillian yes. You are on the right track. You already have an answer by another user. Check it. Feel free to accept it if it meets your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$2*BC = BC + BC $

$= BC + AC $ (tangents from a common point to a circle are equal common-point C )

$= BF + FC + CD + AD$

$= EF + FC + CD + DE $ (tangents from a common point to a circle are equal )

$= CD + FC + DF $

$=$ Perimeter of the triangle

Comment: @Lillian, it is used here to upvote **any** answer that you think is helpful and, after some times ellapsed, then choose one and *accept it*. In this case, the above gives you the whole, complete answer.